# Avoiding Monaco decorations being clipped?

Tags: css, monaco-editor

Monaco editor has several interfaces for creating decorations or overlays.  These appear to be rendered into one of two places in the DOM:

1. `.monaco-editor` > `.overflow-guard` > `.overlayWidgets` > `.monaco-editor-hover`
2. `.monaco-editor` > `.overflowingContentWidgets`

I am finding that using the line decorations API, the overlays are rendered into location (1), and that's a problem:

[image: Clipped line decoration]

This happens because `.overflow-guard` has overflow (surprise!) set to 'hidden'.

Sample code:

```js
editorInstance.getModel().deltaDecorations(decorations.current, [
  {
    range: new monaco.Range(err.line, err.pos, err.line, err.pos + err.str.length),
    options: {
      className: 'error',
      glyphMarginClassName: 'error_line',
      glyphMarginHoverMessage: { value: err.message },
      overviewRuler: { color: '#ff0000', position: monaco.editor.OverviewRulerLane.Full }
    }
  }
]);
```

This is an instance of an [`IModelDecorationOptions`](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.imodeldecorationoptions.html).

**Questions**:

- Is it possible to modify my code to do this in a way that renders the decoration outside of `overflow-guard`?
- Is there a monaco bug here?  (I couldn't find a way to test it on the playground)